# Problem scraping a url that has src = embed # async_embed using [cheerio]

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

*Hello devs,*

*I am trying to take some data related to covid19 in my country from the following website*

```js
const url = https://e.infogram.com/dab81851-e3af-4767-b1f5-9b54eb900274?parent_url=https%3A%2F%2Festadisticas.pr%2Fen%2Fcovid-19&src=embed#async_embed
```

using the cheerio library, but apparently I cannot access the data.

*If there is a way in which the data can be accessed, I will appreciate it.*

***index.js***

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios').default;

const main = async() =>{
  const url = 'https://e.infogram.com/dab81851-e3af-4767-b1f5-9b54eb900274?parent_url=https%3A%2F%2Festadisticas.pr%2Fen%2Fcovid-19&src=embed#async_embed'
  const {data} = await axios.get(url, {method: 'GET'});
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  console.log($.html())
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

That data is in a json blob:

```
let match = data.match(/window.infographicData=(\{.*?\});/)
let parsed = JSON.parse(match[1])
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I am trying to do the same thing for COVID-19 data from Puerto Rico